# Wordpress media upload images not showing

Tags: wordpress, image-upload

In my twentyfourteen wordpress blog when i try to upload image it is uploaded to uploads folder but not showing in wordpress backend. also this happen only when i try to set featured image. i am using wordpress twentyfourteen theme.

this is the error i am getting.

> An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your server support GD2 to resize image and your upload folder is writable.

Comment: It 's a php extension for image programming, you can check it here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GD_Graphics_Library. To check your server support or not, you just need to run phpinfo() and see